# Why is the spectrum of the Laplace operator positive?

Tags: spectral-theory, harmonic-functions, laplacian

I took a look at the Lax-Milgram method and using Rayleigh quotient and the max-min principle it is clear that the Laplace Operator should have a positive specturm. However, if I take $L : [0,1] \to \mathbb C$,  $Lf(x) = -f''(x)$, 
and $f(x) = \sin(ix)$, I have

$$Lf(x) = -\sin''(ix) = -(i\cos'(ix)) = - (-i^2\sin(ix)) = -\sin(ix),$$ so $-1$ is an eigenvalue. Where am I wrong?

Comment: The spectrum depends on your choice of boundary conditions, but actually the Laplace operator generally has a *negative* spectrum. We often write $-\Delta$ specifically to switch it the other way. That said, your example doesn't work the way you say it works: $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(\sin(ix))=\sin(ix)$, so that you have an eigenvalue of $1$...provided that $\sin(ix)$ satisfies the boundary conditions of interest. Without any boundary conditions there is very little meaning to the spectrum of the Laplace operator.

Comment: @Ian The OP defines $L$ to be $-d^2/dx^2$, so for them the minus sign is incorporated in the definition of Laplacian. (The [differential geometer's Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operators_in_differential_geometry) vs analyst's Laplacian...)

Comment: @zaq That wasn't there at the time of my comment.

Answer (score 1):

As Ian said, the spectrum of the Laplacian operator is normally considered on a function space with some boundary condition, e.g. Dirichlet or Neumann. Either of those conditions would exclude $\sin ix$ (which is simply a multiple of $e^x-e^{-x}$) from consideration.

We need boundary conditions to show that Laplacian is a symmetric operator, and to promote it to self-adjoint by suitably extending the domain of definition. Only then does its spectrum become a useful tool.

Answer (score 0):

(This is more a commentary to @zaq answer than an answer in itself). Consider the function $f(x)=e^{kx}$, with $k\in\mathbb C$. You have the formula, analogous to your example,
$$ 
-\frac{d^2}{dx^2} f= -k^2 f.$$
So, any complex number can be an eigenvalue of $-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$, if you do not specify some additional condition. See [Example 5](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/the-spectral-theorem-and-its-converses-for-unbounded-symmetric-operators/) here.